# Excel: A function to replicate built-in change in relative references when copying formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I need a function that will do what Excel does automatically when you dreag a formula: change the referneces automatically.

For example: 
In A1 I have "= A2 + A3"

If i copy this to say C3 it will have: "= C4 + C5"

I need to WRITE a formula in C3 that will produce this.

Any ideas? VBA solution is also welcome

CLARIFICATION:

In need this to be as general as possible. 
Meaning A1 can contain ANY formula of any type, containing references to other cells. 
for example: "= A2 + A3" or "= VLOOKUP(A2, $C$1:$E$7, 2, True)"

In need to move have this formula, whatever it is, copied to another cell (say C3), w/o the built in copy/paste, and have the references (that aren't set with $) change relatively.

I thought there might be a function to write in the destination file to do this.

I have tried writing an Eval function, and i managed to copy the formula from A1 and have it evaluated in C3, but the references would not change

Comment: What do you mean? What would the formula have to do??

Comment: I added some clarifications, thank you

Comment: Remember to select one of the answers as your solution if your question was answered. It'll let other people who have the same problem know what worked for you...

Answer (score 0):

This question lacks a bit of clarity, but I think this *might* be what you're after:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(C3,1,0,2))
```

This will sum the two cells directly below the given cell (in this case, cell `C3`). That is, it *offsets* `C3` by 1 row, 0 columns, and grabs a *height* of 2 cells and then passes the result to the SUM function.

Answer (score 0):

This VBA code would do what you are looking by setting the formula in the active cell:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[+1]C+R[+2]C"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Indirect()` function using relative reference style.

For example, if you were in A1 and wanted to sum B1 & C1, it would look as follows:

```
A1:  =INDIRECT("RC[1]",0)+INDIRECT("RC[2]",0)
```

That will change as you move the cell around to always sum the 2 cells to the left of the cell.

For your specific example (A1 = A2 + A3 || C3 = C4 + C5), it would be as follows:

```
=INDIRECT("R[1]C",0)+INDIRECT("R[2]C",0)
```

Hope that does the trick!!

Comment: Glad it worked - Remember to select one of the answers as your solution if your question was answered. It'll let other people who have the same problem know what worked for you